# Unity Complete Editor Become Pink - Unity Editor Bug

Tags: unity-game-engine

Whole Unity Editor becomes pink, I don't know what happened wrong with the editor.

Here is the screenshot of the editor:
[image]

I have changed Color Space settings from Gamma to Linear and all things become pink.
[Linear or gamma workflow](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/LinearRendering-LinearOrGammaWorkflow.html?_ga=2.163831423.1939683802.1573474847-96643220.1573474847)

I have restarted Unity multiple times but nothing changed.

I hope I will not lose my project data because of this. I can't able to find any way to change settings back to Gamma.

**NOTE:** Within the same project, I started getting this problem. My other projects don't face this kind of problem.

Comment: What version of Unity are you using? Also, when you open a new or another project do you see the same issue?

Comment: At the header of my attached image, you can see exact Unity version.

Comment: if you found a bug in unity pleased submit it to unity

Comment: Where to submit this issue?

Comment: Under help theres a report bug...

Comment: Did you try to turn it off and on again ;)

Comment: I have multiple time open and closed the Unity and even switched the computer too but its same thing happening for the same project :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems to be a bug!

---

**Hotfix for reverting the change**

With an external texteditor open the file

```
ProjectSettings/ProjectSettings.asset
```

and find the entry

```
m_ActiveColorSpace = 1
```

it should be `1` for `Gamma`

and change it back to `0` for `Linear`

```
m_ActiveColorSpace = 0
```

then open the project in Unity again.

This should hopefully revert the change.

Comment: okay let me try the above solution - a few minutes ago, I have submitted the bug report.